# How to fix replit not loading files?

Tags: file, load, replit, replit-database

As you can see in the image below, I'm not able to open any file from replit. And the files are not being loaded in the replit.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63xMp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add some files in it. If already there, try to find "show files" button

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).